# Hide child elements which are cropped due to overflow hidden property

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Although there are many similar question posted around this topic, there are no apt answers present.

Here, overflow hidden property is applied to parent div. I want to show only those child elements which are visible 100% in this container. As shown in picture, I want to hide 3rd item which is cropped.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;

}

  .item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
    width: 40%;
}

#i1{ height: 32px; }
#i2{ height: 64px; }
#i3{ height: 48px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="i1" class="item">
      item 1
    </div>
    <div id="i2" class="item">
      item 2
    </div>
    <div id="i3" class="item">
      item 3
    </div>
   

</div>
```

Comment: *"for IE7"* In 2022? ;-)

Comment: You've included the [tag:javascript] tag. Does that mean you're happy with a JavaScript-based solution rather than a CSS solution?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you do not want to set the height of the block `wrapper`?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, CSS would be better option for me. But if CSS cannot handle this scenario then js solution would also be appreciated

Comment: @AndreiFedorov
 No, here I want to remove 3rd element which is getting cropped because of overflow-x property.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you're okay with statically setting the height of the wrapper to the height of the highest item (but keep reading if not), you can make the items wrap by removing the `white-space: nowrap` and adding `overflow-y: hidden;` (along with `height`):

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* <=== */
    height: 64px;       /* <=== */
    width: 200px;
}
```

Live Example:

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden; /* <=== */
    height: 64px;       /* <=== */
    width: 200px;
}

.item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
    width: 40%;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#i1{ height: 32px; }
#i2{ height: 64px; }
#i3{ height: 48px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="i1" class="item">
      item 1
    </div>
    <div id="i2" class="item">
      item 2
    </div>
    <div id="i3" class="item">
      item 3
    </div>
</div>
```

That works because the child elements are `inline-block`, and when the last child wraps, it's hidden because the parent isn't tall enough to show it.

---

Assuming you don't want to do that, I can't think of a way other than JavaScript:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const wrapperBox = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
for (const child of wrapper.children) {
    const childBox = child.getBoundingClientRect();
    child.classList.toggle("hidden", overflows(wrapperBox, childBox));
}

function overflows(parentBox, childBox) {
    return childBox.right > wrapperBox.right ||
        childBox.bottom > wrapperBox.bottom ||
        childBox.left < wrapperBox.left ||
        childBox.top < wrapperBox.top;
}
```

That would need to be re-run whenever the layout changed, unlike the CSS example where the browser would effectively do that for you.

Live Example:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const wrapperBox = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
for (const child of wrapper.children) {
    const childBox = child.getBoundingClientRect();
    child.classList.toggle("hidden", overflows(wrapperBox, childBox));
}

function overflows(parentBox, childBox) {
    return childBox.right > wrapperBox.right ||
        childBox.bottom > wrapperBox.bottom ||
        childBox.left < wrapperBox.left ||
        childBox.top < wrapperBox.top;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 200px;

}

.item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* for IE7*/
    *zoom:1;/* for IE7*/
    width: 40%;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}

#i1{ height: 32px; }
#i2{ height: 64px; }
#i3{ height: 48px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="i1" class="item">
      item 1
    </div>
    <div id="i2" class="item">
      item 2
    </div>
    <div id="i3" class="item">
      item 3
    </div>
   

</div>
```